# Submit Facebook App for Approval - Why?

Tags: facebook

I'm just about to deploy my app, and I use Facebook login.

I have an iOS version, and an Android version.

I've just noticed that in the developer console of Facebook there's a place for submitting it to Facebook for review.

The app is working fine now, and I have no need for it to be promoted by Facebook. Also, I have no custom open graph stories or something like that.

What is the motivation for submitting it to Facebook for review? Is it something I must do? If so, where does it say that? Is the app sanctioned in any way if it's not reviewed?

Comment: You only need to submit it if you use actions (wether if custom or not).

Comment: Actions as in graph actions? if I just use basic sharing dialogs, it's ok?

Comment: Yes - as long as everything you want works without submitting it to FB it does not need submitted to FB. ;)

Comment: Great. I fear it's an umbrella thing I'll never see coming :)